# Putting content under a row that takes up 100% of the viewport in bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a web page that starts with a image next to some text. I got that to work but when I try to put content under that it works on desktop but when the columns get stacked the content below covers the second column. I don't do a heap of web design so this might be a easy fix.

**Here are some images:**
These images are scrolled down the image fill the whole viewport.

[Working on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Acbi.png)

[Not working when stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYPQg.png)

**Here is my code:**

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Name</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row vh-100">
        <div id="welcomeImg" class="col-lg-4 h-100 welcomeImg" style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1080x1920?text=Image');">
          <div class="h-100" id="mobileOverlay">
            <div class='icon-scroll'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <h3>text</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. At consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Consequat semper viverra nam libero.</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Scripts-->
    <!-- BootStrap -->
    <script src="vendors/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Others -->
    <script src="resources\js\reactive.js"></script><!--This is just a script that hides the mobileOverlay div if the display is over a certain size. The issue still happends with this removed-->
    
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.welcomeImg {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* A scroll animation by Khalil Benihoud on code pen https://codepen.io/khalilbenihoud/pen/wBJVLK */

.icon-scroll,
.icon-scroll:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
.icon-scroll {
  width: 40px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  top: 80%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.icon-scroll:before {
  content: '';
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: -4px;
  top: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
          animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: scroll;
          animation-name: scroll;
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(46px);
  }
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(46px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take away the `vh-100` class from the row and give it to the div with the id `welcomeImg` instead of the `h-100` class. This should do the trick.

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="welcomeImg" class="col-lg-4 vh-100 welcomeImg" style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1080x1920?text=Image');">
        <div class="h-100" id="mobileOverlay">
          <div class='icon-scroll'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <h3>text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. At consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Consequat semper viverra nam libero.</h5>
    </div>   
  </div>
</body>
```